# Measure the height of bar chart using python or R

Tags: python, r

A set of research data I need is not available, so I have to get an estimate of the data from this bar chart below. I wonder if there is a way using Python or R to measure the height of each bar, so I can calculate the corresponding values based on the Y axis?

I can't do this manually due to concerns with errors and the large size of the whole figure (most of the parts are not shown here).

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi there! Maybe the ```magick``` package can be of help.

Comment: It can work. The question is, do you have this chart in better quality than what you put in your question?

Comment: @MarekFiołka, yes, I can enlarge the image on my PC and crop it into pieces, then it should have a better quality. Do you want me to update the figure here?

Comment: Please give it the best quality you have.

Comment: @MarekFiołka I have updated the figure, if you click on it, it should enlarge, I hope this figure is clear.

Comment: Wuestion also is at which precision you need the data / how much error do you accept? If you need it with two decimal places precision I guess it gets tricky. If you need it like 30.5 vs 43.0 or so, that might work.

Comment: I may be simpler to use an online tool. Use a search engine with the terms: digitize graph image.

Comment: @deschen Not very high precision, consider the scale is from 0-120, integers or one decimal place are totally acceptable, way better than manual approach in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(png)
png = readPNG("GsWv1.png", native = FALSE, info = FALSE)

a1 = (2882-191)/27
b1 = 191-a1
a2 = (2916-230)/27
b2 = 230-a2

ncol1 = (1:28)*a1+b1
ncol2 = (1:28)*a2+b2
nrows = 9:413
rows=9:413
scale=98/300

fbar = function(png, rows, col){
  col = round(round(png[rows,col,1], 2)+ 
                round(png[rows,col,2], 2)+
                round(png[rows,col,3], 2), 2)
  sum(col>0.5 & col <1.5)
}


df = tibble(data = 1:28) %>% 
  mutate(redval = map(data, ~fbar(png, rows, .x*a1+b1)),
         greenval = map(data, ~fbar(png, rows, .x*a2+b2))) %>% 
  unnest(c(redval, greenval)) %>% 
  mutate(data = data %>% factor(), #Adjust this mutation
         redval=redval*scale, 
         greenval = greenval*scale) %>% 
  pivot_longer(redval:greenval) %>% 
  mutate(name = name %>% fct_inorder())

df %>% ggplot(aes(data, value, fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",  position=position_dodge())
```

[image]

Attention! This will only work for a png sized 998x132 points! You may need to slightly adjust the values. Do it there, I wrote a comment.

**Update 1**

Oops! I made a small mistake in my comments. The png file size must be exactly 2,956 x 418 pixels. Just in case, I attach the data read from this chart below.

```
structure(list(data = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 
25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
"26", "27", "28"), class = "factor"), name = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("redval", "greenval"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(19.6, 17.64, 32.0133333333333, 33.32, 18.2933333333333, 
    16.66, 43.12, 37.8933333333333, 47.04, 35.9333333333333, 
    48.3466666666667, 42.7933333333333, 20.9066666666667, 15.3533333333333, 
    70.8866666666667, 29.0733333333333, 11.4333333333333, 6.86, 
    114.66, 114.986666666667, 48.3466666666667, 35.9333333333333, 
    90.16, 84.28, 18.62, 20.9066666666667, 23.52, 30.7066666666667, 
    42.7933333333333, 45.4066666666667, 41.8133333333333, 13.0666666666667, 
    46.06, 50.96, 38.5466666666667, 25.8066666666667, 46.7133333333333, 
    20.9066666666667, 32.0133333333333, 26.7866666666667, 83.9533333333333, 
    83.6266666666667, 61.74, 63.0466666666667, 10.4533333333333, 
    6.53333333333333, 85.26, 24.5, 40.8333333333333, 37.24, 2.94, 
    2.94, 19.6, 16.66, 25.1533333333333, 19.6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-56L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Below I also attach the original picture from which I read the values.

[image]

Comment: Excuse me, I still can't get it working. I resized the png to 998x132. But when I read it into R, its dimension is ``132  998  4``. When I run ``df = tibble(data = 1:28) ...``, I got the error: `` Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `redval`.
i `redval = map(data, ~fbar(png, rows, .x * a1 + b1))`.
x subscript out of bounds.``.  I also tried ``png = png[,,1]``, but the error remains. I would really appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer, now everything should work fine.

Comment: I'm glad that I helped. Remember that on Stack Overflow you say thank you by selecting the approved solution.

Comment: I really really would like to approve it, I also saw others upvoted it. But after using the png's original size of 2956x418, I get the error of "file is not in PNG format" when I read it. I didn't want to keep bothering you. But still I haven't made it yet.

Comment: Convert any graphics program jpg to png. That's all. It has to work! If you are working in Chrome, right-click on the image and select "Save image as ...". Google Chrome saves files as png by default.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is a png, just R tells me it is not (this error didn't happen for the size of 998x132), this is why I am really so confused. Anyway, you have already worked out this. I may have to try your solution on a different machine. I really appreciate your help! I will approve it!